# JavaImporter throwing IllegalStateException and EcmaError when I try to import java packages in Rhino or create new Java instances with the Packages

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

I am now having trouble with Rhino in Android in libGdx.

My Javascript code is this:

```
var packages = JavaImporter();
var game;

function create(app)
{
    game = app;
}

function render(batch)
{

}

function resize(width, height)
{

}

function pause()
{

}

function resume()
{

}
```

I have my two relevant classes.

RhinoScriptManager.java

```
public class RhinoScriptManager
{
    public String script;

    private Context context;
    private ScriptableObject scope;

    public RhinoScriptManager(FileHandle script)
    {
        this(script.readString());
    }

    public RhinoScriptManager(String script)
    {
        this.script = script;
        context = Context.enter();
        context.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
        context.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_8);
        scope = context.initStandardObjects();

        context.evaluateString(scope, script, "<javascript>", 1, null);
    }

    public Function getFunction(String funcName)
    {
        return (Function)scope.get(funcName);
    }

    public Object callFunction(String funcName, Object...args)
    {
        return getFunction(funcName).call(context, scope, scope, args);
    }

    public void endScript()
    {
        Context.exit();
    }

    public Scriptable getScope()
    {
        return scope;
    }
}
```

MyGdxGame.java

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game
{
    RhinoScriptManager manager;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        manager = new RhinoScriptManager(Gdx.files.internal("entry.js"));
        manager.callFunction("create", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        manager.callFunction("render", Assets.gameMap.getBatch())
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        manager.callFunction("resize", width, height);
    }

  @Override
    public void pause()
    {
        manager.callFunction("pause");
    }

  @Override
    public void resume()
    {
        manager.callFunction("resume");
    }

      @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        manager.callFunction("dispose");

        manager.endScript();
    }
}
```

The code throws an IllegalStateException at line 5 in my javascript for `JavaImporter();`. I have tried modifying it to `packages = new JavaImporter()` but I get the same results.

I have alternatively tried to create Textures like so in my js because the web is filled with examples of people creating Java object instances in rhino:

```
var tex = new Packages.com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture(new Packages.com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle("android.jpg"));
```

I then modified my render function like this:

```
function render(batch)
{
    batch.draw(tex, 10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

But when I do this it throws an EcmaError "Reference error", saying Packages is not defined. Now, if I was correct, when I call `Context.initStandardObjects();` it should, as the name implies, return a Scriptable (my "scope") with the standard library objects, such as the Math libraries as well as Rhino-specific things like the `JavaImporter` or the `Packages` object. Upon further reading I learned that this does not make these functions available though.

For Android I have to disable Rhino JIT optimizations. Is this getting in the way of my being able to create java instances in the script? If so how can I get around this? If not, how can I fix this?

If I call `importPackage(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture);` I will get an EcmaError com undefined. [Where I read this.](http://www.webr2.com/how-can-i-import-my-java-packages-into-a-js-file/)

The easiest way to create a Java instance from Rhino so far is to create a method in my main game Object and pass it to Rhino in the `app` constructor of my `create` function. Then I make a copy of it available globally in my script. For example, in my main Gdx class, I created a method like this:

```
public Texture newTexture(String fileName)
{
    return new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName);
}
```

This will create a new libGdx `Texture` and return it. Now, to call it from js I would do this:

```
var game;
var newTex;

//Pass the ApplicationListener to the create function
//and create a global copy in-script.
function create(app)
{
    game = app;
    newTex = game.newTexture("android.jpg");
}

//Now we render the new Texture
function render(batch)
{
    batch.draw(newTex, 10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

This seems like overkill and there has to be a better way than creating a method to make instances of every java object I need to instantiated in JavaScript.

I have also read the [mozilla pages related to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java) As well as [other pages](http://www.webr2.com/how-can-i-import-my-java-packages-into-a-js-file/)

Answer (score 0):

After doing a considerable amount of digging, I finally figured out why the Rhino LiveConnect features don't work. I read [this article](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6655807) and learned that this feature requires optimization, and can not be used in interpreted mode in android due to the DVM. Since the optimizations only create class files, and not dex files, the DVM is unable to use LiveConnect. The best way to work around this in the Javascript is to make a thin framework for the API you are using. In my case it would be creating a ResourceManager Java object and passing it to my javascript function as an argument.

```
public class ResourceManager
{
    //Creates a new Texture.
    public Texture CreateTexture(String file)
    {
        return new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(file));
    }

    public SpriteBatch CreateBatch()
    {
        return new SpriteBatch();
    }
}
```

And in the JavaScript using my RhinoScriptManager class in the question add:

```
public ScriptableObject getObject(String objName)
{
    return scope.get(objName);
}

public Function getObjFunction(String obj, String function)
{
    return (Function)getObject(obj).get(function);
}

public Object callObjFunc(String obj, String func, Object...args)
{
    return getObjFunction(obj, func).call(context, scope, scope, args);
}
```

Because I have a game object I need to call functions to.